# Query for counting how many times a value in one column exists in another column of the same table

Tags: sql

Table

```
id  A   B 
1   3   5
2   1   3
3   7   8
4   5   3
5   2   5
6   11  5
```

I want the result

```
A   count
3   2
5   3
```

Count : how many times that A exist in B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to self-join the (anonymous) table with itself.

```
SELECT A1.A, COUNT(*)
  FROM Anonymous AS A1
  JOIN Anonymous AS A2 ON A1.A = A2.B
 GROUP BY A1.A;
```